# Scale Shapes or Patterns

Tags: scales

I'm really confused with this. The CAGED system. It talks about scale patterns, 1,2,3,4,5. And then calls a given pattern or position the "E" shape for example, or G, or A, whatever. Does that actually have something to do with a physical shape? I'm getting bogged down with this.

Answer (score 2):

From a chord shape perspective, it represents the 5 basic 'open' shapes that major chords can be played with on guitar.Each one can then be played with a similar shape, with a barre behind it, Couple of examples - use the E shape, but barre on the 7th fret, we make C. Use the A shape but barre on the 3rd fret, we make C again. Use the open C shape, but barre on the 5th fret, we get F. The one I feel is a little nebulous is the D shape, which only gives 4 (or 5) strings, and to me isn't that good to play. Put all the letters together to make CAGED.

Now, when it comes to the scale side of CAGED, it's a bit more hazy. Using the chord shape as a starting point, that will give us the 1, 3 and 5 of the major scale, and once we can establish the 1, we fill the gaps, using the actual string/fret places found in the chord. 6th string for E and G, 5th for A and C, and 4th for D.

Some players find this mapping helpful - I don't particularly. Rather like some will use a 4 fret span, and play scale notes below and above the root - as for example, the E shape on 5th fret, giving the root on bottom string on that 5th fret, but the 4th fret is also available with a finger ready for it. Play from there, and you have G# Locrian. Clever stuff! - but not that useful - to me at least!

Answer (score 1):

The open/barre chord shapes that you are probably familiar with are contained within the pattern.

For example if you take an open C chord starting on the 3rd fret of the 5th string you have the C, E, and G notes of the C major scale. If you then fill in the other notes of C major around this chord fingering you'll have the CAGED "C" shape in open position.

But I wouldn't worry too much about the reasoning behind the names. I've never found that aspect of CAGED that helpful. Just learn the shapes and call them what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The **E** shape contains the shape of an open **E** chord voicing, the **G** shape contains the shape of an open **G** voicing, etc. I think this is just a mnemonic to help players familiar with the standard Mel Bay open chord voicings remember the shapes and identify chord tones within the scale shapes.